# Negative value for PSNR after image enhancment in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-enhancement

I have done this so far. After image enhancement in frequency domain for assessment, I have calculated PSNR. The value of PSNR and SNR is negative.

Further, the class of input and output image is double.

```
ref = imread('img.tif');
ref=im2double(ref);
%A = processing(ref);
%Calculate the PSNR.
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A, ref);
```

Can someone help me further?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22741/is-it-possible-to-have-negative-psnr may be relevant. As far as I know, the MATLAB psnr function simply follows the equations and does not do anything fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are converting `ref` into double, why are you converting it into double? `psnr` will never be negative as per the definition [PSNR](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/psnr.html)

Please try these code first and then into your problem:

```
ref = imread('pout.tif');
A = imnoise(ref,'salt & pepper', 0.02);
% Calculate the PSNR.
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A, ref);
fprintf('\n The Peak-SNR value is %0.4f', peaksnr);
fprintf('\n The SNR value is %0.4f \n', snr);
```

Out of the above code is:

```
The Peak-SNR value is 22.6437
The SNR value is 15.5524
```

In your case, just try following:

```
ref = imread('img.tif');
A = processing(im2double(ref));% what does it do?
% Check the type of A, is it uint8 data type, if not then convert it to that 
%Calculate the PSNR.
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(uint8(A), ref);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: " why are you converting it into double? " for frequency filtering.

Comment: if you not convert into double then its sum might be wrong because after some range depending upon MATLAB version i.e integer range is 2^32 or 2^64, so what happen after 2^32 sum values, it will loop and start from Zeros.